# How to read test files one by one

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a project in which I need to read text files in programs directory and check for specific keywords in it. An example: folder contains files with some name (not specific) and I want to read them one by one to check for specific string in them, until all are checked. I've been looking for method to read files like that but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is one way of doing it

```
    Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\123")
    Dim aryFi As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles("*.txt")
    Dim fi As IO.FileInfo

    For Each fi In aryFi
        Dim MyStream As New StreamReader(fi.FullName)
        Dim txt As String = MyStream.ReadToEnd
        MsgBox(txt)
    Next
```

you check if txt.contains("blabla") then you do whatever you want..

Comment: `New StreamReader(di.ToString + "\" + fi.ToString)`. Nope.`New StreamReader(IO.Path.Combine(di.ToString, fi.ToString))`. Better, but still no. `New StreamReader(fi.FullName)`. That's more like it.

Comment: If you're not going to use any of the functionality of the `DirectoryInfo` and `FileInfo` classes then don't use the classes.  The `Directory.GetFiles` method returns a `String` array containing the file paths so, if file paths is all you need, that's what you should use.

Comment: Edited, ofc FullName SHOULD be used but VS somehow didn't like it until i restarted it xD it made me think i missed a dim or something :) fi's FullName hint was missing, still using vs2013 update 2